# Can't make my desired content be within my div element

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to eliminate this transparent area on this page under the header:
The code is here:

style.css:

```
  .kordpage {
  position: relative;
  color: 111;
  width: 1000px;
  max-height: 1300px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: left;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px 25px 25px 25px;
  -moz-border-image: url(images/border.png) 47 48 46 repeat;
  -webkit-border-image: url(images/border.png) 47 48 46 repeat;
  -o-border-image: url(images/border.png) 47 48 46 repeat;
  border-image: url(images/border.png) 47 48 46 repeat;
  display:block;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

The page

```
<?php

/*
Template Name>Special Layout
status = in use
Template Name: Travel-Googlemaps */

get_header(); ?>
<div class="kordpage">
<div class="textus">
<?php
if (have_posts()) :
  while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>



  <article class="post page">
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    </article>
    <iframe allowfullscreen="" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d1760.23786890098!2d20.275166016484622!3d63.8206487834489!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x467c5b066d574471%3A0x3c132dfbfa054972!2sSliperiet!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sse!4v1454590960458" style="border:0" height="400" width="600" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    <img alt="" src=".../9837.jpg"  style=";width:950px;">
  </div>
  </div>
  <?php endwhile;

  else :
    echo "<p>No Content Found I'm afraid</p>";

  endif;


?>
```

If you inspect the elements you will notice that the kordpage div covers the area but my white baground(textus) div elements doesn't.

I suspect the problem is with the border, I am going to sleep soon so I might not see your answers before 10 hours, but I highly appreciate any help or suggestions!

Comment: If you're talking about the whitespace below the blue navbar, there's a `<br>` under the `.BGheader` div that's doing that.

Comment: Actually, I think you need to apply `margin-top:0;` to your first h2.

Comment: Insert  "margin-top: -17px;" in the class .textus style.css.

Comment: Remove the margin from the top of your h2 tag, that is what is causing the transparent space (grey bar) under the header. `.page h2{ margin-top: 0px;}`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, highly appreciated!
Turns out it was the h2 margin-top as you had suggested:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transparent space between .navmenu and .kordpage (The grey bar under the menu) is being made by the margin-top of your h2 tag. This CSS rule removes that margin and gets rid of the transparent space.

```
.page h2{ margin-top: 0px;}
```

Maybe you would be better off using padding on your h2 tag, you could set margin to 0px and padding to 17px instead.